# php-mysql. Can i compare plain text email (php $_POST) with mysql AES_ENCRYPT value

Tags: php, mysql

I plan to use email as id for login.

User registers, i record in mysql

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` ( `Email` ) VALUES ( AES_ENCRYPT(?, "some_hash") )
```

And for `?` is `$_POST['email']`

When user wants to login, i want to do like this

```
SELECT `Password`, AES_DECRYPT(`Email`, "some_hash") AS `Email` FROM `table_name` WHERE `Email` = AES_ENCRYPT(?, "some_hash")
```

And for `?` again is `$_POST['email']`

This does not work (i can not fetch hashed email). As i understand it is not possible to compare `$_POST` value against mysql `AES_ENCRYPT` value?

**Update**

Sorry, seems all works. Possibly it did not work because of some negligence mistake.

Now I used

```
SELECT `Password`, AES_DECRYPT(`Email`, "some_hash") AS `Email` FROM `table_name` WHERE `Email` = AES_ENCRYPT(?, "some_hash")
```

and get array with password and email.

Here is updated working code:

```
try {
$stmt = $db->prepare( '
SELECT `Password` 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `Email` = AES_ENCRYPT(?, "some_hash")  
;' );
$stmt->execute( array( trim($_POST['email']) ) );
$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

With `WHERE Email = AES_ENCRYPT(?, "some_hash")` i hash (`AES_ENCRYPT`) `trim($_POST['email'])` and compare it with hashed value in mysql column `Email`.

Comment: `AES_DECRYPT(Email, "some_hash")` - that function requires a (user input) string, not the hash value - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt i.e.: `AES_DECRYPT(crypt_str,key_str[,init_vector])`

Comment: Seems all works. I updated my question with code that works. If any comments / advises, please, write

Comment: I seem to not be grasping the question fully. Seeing the `?`, suggests that you want to use a prepared statement (?=placeholder), am I right?

Comment: Yes, prepared statement. All works. If nee whole code, i will post.

Comment: Whats the definition of the field **`email`**. it is possible thats to short und the value is truncated. the field length is calculated = **16 * (trunc(string_length / 16) + 1)**

Comment: `$_PSOT` is that a typo? It should read as `$_POST`. @user2118559

Comment: @user2118559 I stayed here for a while. I asked about if that above was a typo; no response. I honestly don't know what you're asking here and what the problem is. If you want me back in the question, you will need to ping me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I closed computer yesterday and only now opened again. `$PSOT` is negligence mistake. Problem was that i could not fetch email from mysql. Now problem is solved. Thank you for time and excuse me for negligence.

Comment: @BerndBuffen `Email` type is `varbinary(255)` I had problem because of incorrect code (`select` query). Last pasted code works for me.